# Boot hangs at "Finished Record Runlevel Change in UTMP." on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, runlevel

So I recently have been working on installing **GNOME** on my Ubuntu 22.04, but during boot, it hangs at "Finished Record Runlevel Change in UTMP." How can I resolve this issue?

When I installed Ubuntu in the past on the host provider, I never ran into this issue, until now. The expected outcome should include reaching the login screen interface.

Thanks in advance

[image: boot-progress-hanging]